# How to pass parameter in Stream.map method

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

What does the below statement mean:

```
String joined = elements.stream()
  .map(Object::toString)
  .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

As I understand, `Stream.map` accepts a parameter of type `Function`. 
I don't understand how `Object::toString` is being passed and how it works?

Thanks.

Comment: `Object::toString` is method reference

Comment: It is a shorthand for `element -> element.toString()` here

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Comment: Please, don't downvote the question just because the author is new to Java. The question looks absolutely correct.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov I suspect the downvotes are for lack of research. You can easily find tutorials and related questions about this by searching for `Object::toString`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How `Object::toString` is being passed and how it works?

It is called **method reference** in which you are telling to **use the existing `toString` method definition (from `Object` class) for the `map` method**, rather than you explicitly calling `obj -> obj.toString()` inside the `map` method.

I suggest you look at [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) and understand on how method references work in Java8.